# Github "permission denied (public key)" despite public key being added and keys regenerated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, ssh

I was first using multiple ssh keys using a config file. Now the need for multiple keys went away and I deleted those keys+the the config file.

After this github gives me the permission denied (publickey) error when trying to push.

I thought It might be a key problem so I deleted the ssh keys in my ~/.ssh/ folder and generated them again following the Github manual. I also added the public key again to the ssh-keys within the github account settings.

This does not solve the problem.

The next thing I did was this:

```
eval $(ssh-agent) > /dev/null
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

After doing this I can do a git push. They do ask me to enter my passphrase which I find weird since I normally do not have to do this.

After closing the cmd windows they keep asking for my passphrase when trying to push again.
After a restart I have to do the whole ssh agent thing again since I get the public error again.

Can somebody help me fix this problem?

I am running windows 8.1 and installed Ruby on Rails using railsinstaller. This also included Github.

Full errors I am getting:

```
$ git push
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

and

```
$ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.130] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh
debug1: no match: libssh-0.6.0
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I think the problem lies in the fact that the ssh manager does not remember the key. How do I set this up? Railsinstaller did this for me in the first install. I messed this up somewhere and I need to have it working again like before.

Comment: can you post your full error?

Comment: Although it normally picks up the right key but still do you have more than one key in your system?

Comment: The only thing that is in my .ssh folder right now is id_rsa, id_rsa.pub and a known_hosts file. I have had multiple keys but I just deleted those in that folder and deleted the config file. After that it started acting strange and I have no idea why.